# How to change django FileFiled 'storage' AFTER uploading?

Tags: django, django-models, filefield

I am developing two web sites using the Django framework.
The thing is - one site is sharing part of the content from the other one.
They both use different amazon WS buckets to store images, etc.

So for the site which shares some content with another one I need to specify a different MEDIA_URL, but it seems impossible cause 'upload_to' and 'storage' parameters of the FileField only influence the file being uploaded.

Is there any way to use another storage when displaying image after it was uploaded?

Comment: I realised why using a different storage did not work - I was using a default django.utils FileSystemStorage instead of amazon's S3Storage object.